# Why powershell is not saving the xml file?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am doing find and replace a string in attribute of xml file using powershell. The strings are properly replaced [I verified it by displaying

> "After replace $($Item.Node.$attribute)"

] but in the config file it is not reflected. Seems like it is not saving with latest values properly. I tried all the possibilities but still mysteriously it is not saving. I am using powershell version 2.

```
function Set-XMLAttribute
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # webconfig file full path
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string]$Path,

        # Param2 help description
        [string] $xPath,

        [string] $attribute,

        [string] $valueToFind,

        [string] $ValueToReplace
    )

    Begin { }
    Process
    {
        try 
        {

            If ( Test-path -Path $Path)
            {

                #Loading the file
                $xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
                $xml.Load($Path)

                # Getting all the values
                $Items  = Select-Xml -Path $Path -XPath $xPath
                ForEach ($Item in $Items) 
                {   
                    $Item.Node.$attribute
                    If ($($Item.Node.$attribute).Contains($valueToFind) ){
                        "Before Replace the value $($Item.Node.$attribute)"

                        $Item.Node.$attribute = $($Item.Node.$attribute) -Replace "$valueToFind","$ValueToReplace"


                    }
                    Else {

                        Write-Error "$valueToFind not available"

                    }
                }
                "After replace $($Item.Node.$attribute)"
                "Saving the $Path"
                 $xml.Save((Resolve-Path "$Path"))
            }
            Else 
            {
                Write-Error "$Path is not found"
            }
        }
        catch 
        {

            $_.Exception.Message
            $_.Exception.ItemName
            Write-Error "Set-XMLAttribute function failed."
        }
    }
    End {}
} # End Function Update-XMLAttribute
Set-XMLAttribute -Path "E:\Pshscript\web.Config" -xPath "/configuration/system.serviceModel/behaviors/serviceBehaviors/behavior/serviceMetadata" -attribute "externalMetadataLocation" -valueToFind "http" -ValueToReplace "https"
```

Comment: Do you open PS console as admin? Write rights on the file correct?

Comment: @EduardUta Yes it is open as admin

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're seeing this is that you're making changes to $XML, which is an object in memory.  You have to save these settings to a file to reflect it there, so you do that by calling the .Save() method of $XML, which you're doing.  I think the problem here is that you're trying to save with the following line:

```
$xml.Save((Resolve-Path "$Path"))
```

I believe this syntax is causing the problem, as Resolve-Path returns an object with a Path property.  Try this instead.

```
$xml.Save((Resolve-Path "$Path").Path)
```

Comment: Isnt that what was done with ops code here `$xml.Save((Resolve-Path "$Path"))`?

Comment: @FoxDeploy I have done " $xml.Save((Resolve-Path "$Path"))" . What is wrong with that?

Comment: Ah, I re-read your code and agree with you.  I've edited my answer, please give this a try.

Comment: @FoxDeploy  I tried your latest updates but still it is not working. Totally strange

Comment: Hey man, can you post one of these files (the webconfig files) on pastebin for me to troubleshoot this further?  I'm having a very hard time replicating what should be happening here without the same sort of file.

Comment: @FoxDeploy Our organization doesn't allow . is there any other way to share with you?

Comment: @FoxDeploy It works after i change it to Select-xml -XML $xml instead of Select-xml -path $Path .

Comment: Wow, thanks for providing the answer!  Please remember to revisit this post in a few days and post your correct answer here for others to find.